Dropzone Drag & Drop issue in Laravel
I'm encountering an issue with my Laravel application when using the Dropzone JavaScript library. If I remove id="dropzone-basic", I can add files and submit them, but it affects my design. However, if I add id="dropzone-basic", I can drag and drop files, but when I click submit, it doesn't submit anything. The request is empty.
This is my form:
<form action="{{ route('import-file') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"  class="dropzone needsclick" id="dropzone-basic">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="dz-message needsclick">
                                Drop files here or click to upload
                                <span class="note needsclick">(This is just a demo dropzone. Selected files are <span class="fw-medium">not</span> actually uploaded.)</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fallback">
                                <input name="dataFile" class="form-control" id="dataFile" type="file" value="{{ old('dataFile') }}" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 mt-3 d-flex justify-content-end">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>

and theme dropzone file:
"use strict";!function(){var e=`<div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview">
<div class="dz-details">
  <div class="dz-thumbnail">
    <img data-dz-thumbnail>
    <span class="dz-nopreview">No preview</span>
    <div class="dz-success-mark"></div>
    <div class="dz-error-mark"></div>
    <div class="dz-error-message"><span data-dz-errormessage></span></div>
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" data-dz-uploadprogress></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dz-filename" data-dz-name></div>
  <div class="dz-size" data-dz-size></div>
</div>
</div>`,a=document.querySelector("#dropzone-basic"),a=(a&&new Dropzone(a,{previewTemplate:e,parallelUploads:1,maxFilesize:5,addRemoveLinks:!0,maxFiles:1}),document.querySelector("#dropzone-multi"));a&&new Dropzone(a,{previewTemplate:e,parallelUploads:1,maxFilesize:5,addRemoveLinks:!0})}();


you need to override your id definition for that css attribute.

@LeviZoesch do you mean replace id="dropzone-basic" with another name? But this will change my design

Yes that is correct.
